# Get memory used by a specific field in a specific row with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, memory-management, row

I'm making a private message program and wanted to limit the size to which a user's inbox can grow.  I decided on a field with "sizeUsed" and "sizeAllocate" (to change the size for certain users if need be) - but I'm having a problem finding out how to check the size of a field in a specific row within a PHP script/mysql query.  I googled and stackoverflow searched and couldn't find a solution - does anyone know how to do this?  I thought I'd determine the size of the message fields that belong to a single user ID - does this make sense or am I going about it the wrong way?  If this is the right method, how would I do it?  Thanks.

Comment: is this an instant messenger, or like a mail type program?

Comment: It works more like a mailbox than an instant messenger.

Answer (score 0):

Store the size of each message in a separate field as you write it to the database.

Comment: Sounds good, but how do I find out the memory used for the string that is about to be written?

Comment: I wasn't sure that strlen worked like that, is it a direct correlation to bytes or is there memory overhead when stored?